# Vala error "unknown type name" using enum from camel

Tags: enums, vala

I am writing this code in Vala, using Camel

```
using Camel;
[...]
MimeParser par = new MimeParser();
[...]
par.push_state( MimeParserState.MULTIPART, boundary );
```

I downloaded the **camel-1.2.vapi** from github vala-girs [(this link)](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-girs/tree/master/vala/vapi), put it in a **vapi** subdirectory and compiled with

```
valac --vapidir=vapi --includedir=/usr/include/evolution-data-server/camel --pkg camel-1.2 --pkg posix --target-glib=2.32 -o prog prog.vala -X -lcamel-1.2
```

Compiling I get this error:

```
error: unknown type name "CamelMimeParserState"
 const gchar* camel_mime_parser_state_to_string (CamelMimeParserState self);
```

Looking the C output code I see that the CamelMimeParserState type is used several times **but it is never defined**. It should be a simple **enum** because the **camel-1.2.vapi** file says:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "camel/camel.h", cprefix = "CAMEL_MIME_PARSER_STATE_", has_type_id = false)]
public enum MimeParserState {
            INITIAL,
            PRE_FROM,
            FROM,
            HEADER,
            BODY,
            MULTIPART,
            MESSAGE,
            PART,
            END,
            EOF,
            PRE_FROM_END,
            FROM_END,
            HEADER_END,
            BODY_END,
            MULTIPART_END,
            MESSAGE_END
    }
```

So why doesn't the C output code simply use an enum as the vapi file says (described by **cprefix CAMEL_MIME_PARSER_STATE_**)?

Is there an error in the .vapi file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The vapi file is wrong because the **cname** field is missing. Changing the vapi file adding this **cname="camel_mime_parser_state_t"**:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "camel/camel.h", cname="camel_mime_parser_state_t", cprefix = "CAMEL_MIME_PARSER_STATE_", has_type_id = false)]
public enum MimeParserState {
    INITIAL,
    [...]
```

works correctly.